# Remove double quotes in array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, json

php code:

```
 foreach($location_total_n_4 as $u=> $v)
{ 

 $final_location_total_4 .= "[".$u.",".$v."],";
}
```

i'm sending these values in json.

```
echo json_encode(array(         
"location"=>"$final_location_total_4"
));
```

Result is:

```
  {"location":"[1407110400000,6641],[1407196800000,1566],[1407283200000,3614],[1407369600000,3654],[1407456000000,2918],[1407715200000,3900],[1407715200000,3900],"}
```

Actually I want this value as following:

```
 {"location":[1407110400000,6641],[1407196800000,1566],[1407283200000,3614],[1407369600000,3654],[1407456000000,2918],[1407715200000,3900],[1407715200000,3900]}
```

Comment: You have the quotes because that is a string. Why don't you echo that in the HTML directly (as javascript)?

Comment: Unless you put quotes elsewhere, this code above doesn't seem to put any extra quotes around your value. A simple echo shouldn't add those quotes around it

Comment: ok,both of you're right.but i'm sending these value in json .so it creates problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   foreach($location_total_n_4 as $u=> $v)
    { 

     $final_location_total_4 .= "[".$u.",".$v."],";
    }
    $final_value =  json_encode(array(         
    "location"=> rtrim($final_location_total_4,',')
    ));

    echo str_replace(']"',']',str_replace('"[',"[",$final_value));
```

This will give you the desired result

Comment: Your code worked.But I already  got solution in json.so,i did with json.you can also check            here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25760340/remove-double-quotes-in-json-result

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning an array nor an object. You are returning a string so it MUST be surrounded by quotes

```
$final_location_total_4 .= "[".$u.",".$v."],";
```

you are effectivelly creating a string `"[4,5],[1,2]"`.
If you want an object or array do this:

```
$final_location_total_4 = array();
foreach($location_total_n_4 as $u=> $v)
{ 
   $final_location_total_4[] = $u.",".$v;
}
```

`{"location":[1407110400000,6641],[140` is completely invalid. you cannot have square brackets separated by commas anywhere else but inside a string. You should be geting a result like: `{"location":{[1407110400000,6641],[140...}`

Comment: already added in php file header('Content-Type: application/json');

Comment: there is no need to add dataType: "json",because i'm just sending only name of user to php file.getting data from php file with name.

Comment: Found a logical error, thus changed the answer alltogether. Please review

Comment: i'm creating graph ,so i need value like this d1=[response.location];             
      
d1=[[1407110400000, 6641], [1407196800000, 1566], [1407283200000, 3614], [1407369600000, 3654], [1407456000000, 2918], [1407715200000, 3900]];