# Remove double quotes in JSON result?

Tags: php, jquery, json

My code is as follows

```
foreach($location_total_n_4 as $u=&gt; $v) {    
  $final_location_total_4 .= "[".$u.",".$v."],"; 
}
```

I'm sending these values as JSON.

```
echo json_encode(array("location"=&gt;"$final_location_total_4" ));
```

Here's how my `response` object looks:

```
{
  "location": "[1407110400000,6641],[1407196800000,1566],[1407283200000,3614],"‌​
}
```

I'm creating graph on success with ajax.so I need it like this,

```
  {
      "location": [1407110400000,6641],[1407196800000,1566],[1407283200000,3614],
    }
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Where do you get this response from? If it's your code returning it  - why not just generate it properly instead?

Comment: foreach($location_total_n_4 as $u=> $v)
{ 

 $final_location_total_4 .= "[".$u.",".$v."],";
}  

i'm sending these values in json.

echo json_encode(array(         
"location"=>"$final_location_total_4"
));

Comment: @Mr7-itsurdeveloper So you're adding double quotes in PHP and you want to remove it with jQuery? What's the use of the foreach loop? Just remove that loop: ``json_encode(array("location"=> $location_total_n_4)); ``

Comment: @StephanVierkant Thought the same way, but the structure the OP wants to work with is a bit different.

Comment: there are so many entries so, i'm combine this with time $location_total_n_4=array_combine($date_d_4,$location_total_4);

  
 foreach($location_total_n_4 as $u=> $v)
{    

  $final_location_total_4 .= "[".$u.",".$v."],";
}

Comment: That's just sub-optimal. Why create another array which structure doesn't suit you right, then iterate over this array to create another one? You could just iterate over `$location_total_4`, creating the result array using data from `$date_d_4 ` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `location` value is non-properly serialized value. It's definitely appropriate to fix on the server-side (looks like one's trying to implement their own json_encode and failing), but it's possible to fix on the client-side as well. One possible approach:

```
var location = JSON.parse('[' + response.location.slice(0,-1) + ']');
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qp061Lbu/). `slice(0,-1)` removes the trailing comma, then the contents are wrapped into brackets, turning them into a proper JSON (at least for the given dataset).

---

As for server-side, turned out I was right: this code...

```
foreach($location_total_n_4 as $u=> $v) { 
  $final_location_total_4 .= "[".$u.",".$v."],"; 
}
echo json_encode(array('location' => "$final_location_total_4"));
```

... is wrong both tactically (always adding a trailing comma) and strategically (one shouldn't solve the task already solved by the language itself). One possible replacement:

```
$locations = array();
foreach ($location_total_n_4 as $u => $v) {
  $locations[] = array($u, $v);
}
echo json_encode(array('location' => $locations));
```

The bottom line: never attempt to implement your own serialization protocol unless you're really know what're you doing.

Comment: result is blank in console ==>Array [  ]

Comment: still blank, result is blank in console ==>Array [ ]

Comment: What does `console.log(typeof response.location)` return?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60947/discussion-between-raina77ow-and-mr7-itsurdeveloper).

Comment: worked,just removed [0] from your code var res = JSON.parse("[" + response.location.slice(0,-1) + "]");

Answer (score 0):

There is a trailing comma(,) in the end So json.parse will throw error so we need to remove that.

```
     b = JSON.parse("["+ data[0].substr(0,data[0].length-1) +"]");
```

Then b becomes

```
     [[1407110400000,6641],[1407196800000,1566],[1407283200000,3614],[1407369600000,3654],[1407456000000,2918],[1407715200000,3900]]
```

without the trailing comma.